# Unreachable code detected in SPFx web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I have created a React Web Part which is trying to show some data in an unordered list. Nothing fancy at all!

I can't for the life of me see what is wrong here but I'm being told my return in the `_onRenderListCell` has unreachable code.

The `<ul>` code block that I've commented out does work.

Am I missing something?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {IColour} from './IColour';

import { List } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/List';
// Import Button component
import { IButtonProps, DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';

export interface IColourListProps
{
    colours: IColour[];
}

export class ColourList extends React.Component<IColourListProps, {}>
{
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IColourListProps>
    {
        return (
            // <ul>
            //     {
            //         this.props.colours.map(colourItem =>
            //             (
            //                 <li>{ colourItem.title } </li>
            //             )

            //         )
            //     }    
            // </ul>

            <List items={this.props.colours} onRenderCell= { this._onRenderListCell} />


        );
    }

    private _onRenderListCell = (colour: IColour, index: number | undefined): JSX.Element => {
    //private _onRenderListCell = (): JSX.Element => {
    return
        (
            <div>
                {colour.title}<br />
                <DefaultButton text="delete" data={colour.id} onClick={ () => this._onButtonClick(colour) } />
            </div>            
        )   
    }

    private _onButtonClick(colour: IColour): void
    {
        console.log('clicked delete for ', colour);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using like this:

```
private _onRenderListCell = (colour: IColour, index: number | undefined): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <div>
        {colour.title}<br />
        <DefaultButton text="delete" data={colour.id} onClick={() => this._onButtonClick(colour)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

OR

```
const _onRenderListCell = (colour: IColour, index: number | undefined): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <div>
        {colour.title}<br />
        <DefaultButton text="delete" data={colour.id} onClick={() => this._onButtonClick(colour)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Not sure what is the issue here (maybe with VS code). But, bringing `(` on same line as `return` seems to be working.

Maybe this: [Warning: unreachable code after return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return)

Comment: Ganesh you are a legend! Thanks so much. I've been staring at that for hours!